# GDALWarpRegionToBuffer & Tiling when Dst Frame not strictly contained in Src Frame

Tags: c++, c, gdal

I'm currently working with gdal api C/C++ and I'm facing an issue with gdal warp region to buffer functionality (WarpRegionToBuffer).

When my destination dataset is not strictly contained in the frame of my source dataset, the area where there should be no data values is filled with random data (see out_code.tif enclosed). However gdalwarp command line functionality, which also uses WarpRegionToBuffer function, does not seem to have this problem.

1/ Here is the code I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "gdal.h"
#include "gdalwarper.h"
#include "cpl_conv.h"


int main(void)
{
    std::string pathSrc = "in.dt1";

    //these datas will be provided by command line 
    std::string pathDst = "out_code.tif";
    
    double resolutionx = 0.000833333;
    double resolutiony = 0.000833333;
    
    //destination corner coordinates: top left (tl) bottom right (br)

    float_t xtl = -1;
    float_t ytl = 45;
    float_t xbr = 2;
    float_t ybr = 41;    
    
    //tile size defined by user
    int tilesizex = 256;
    int tilesizey = 256;
    
    float width = std::ceil((xbr - xtl)/resolutionx);
    float height = std::ceil((ytl - ybr)/resolutiony);

    double adfDstGeoTransform[6] = {xtl, resolutionx, 0, ytl, 0, -resolutiony};

    GDALDatasetH  hSrcDS, hDstDS;

    // Open input file
    GDALAllRegister();
    hSrcDS = GDALOpen(pathSrc.c_str(), GA_ReadOnly);
    GDALDataType  eDT = GDALGetRasterDataType(GDALGetRasterBand(hSrcDS,1));
    
    // Create output file, using same spatial reference as input image, but new geotransform
    GDALDriverH hDriver = GDALGetDriverByName( "GTiff" );
    hDstDS = GDALCreate( hDriver, pathDst.c_str(), width, height, GDALGetRasterCount(hSrcDS), eDT, NULL );

    OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
    char *pszWKT = NULL;

    //force geo projection
    oSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS( "WGS84" );
    oSRS.exportToWkt( &pszWKT );
    GDALSetProjection( hDstDS, pszWKT );
    //Fetches the coefficients for transforming between pixel/line (P,L) raster space,
    //and projection coordinates (Xp,Yp) space.
    GDALSetGeoTransform( hDstDS, adfDstGeoTransform );
        
    // Setup warp options
    GDALWarpOptions *psWarpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
    psWarpOptions->hSrcDS = hSrcDS;
    psWarpOptions->hDstDS = hDstDS;
    psWarpOptions->nBandCount = 1;
    psWarpOptions->panSrcBands = (int *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount );
    psWarpOptions->panSrcBands[0] = 1;
    psWarpOptions->panDstBands = (int *) CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * psWarpOptions->nBandCount );
    psWarpOptions->panDstBands[0] = 1;
    psWarpOptions->pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;
    
    //these datas will be calculated in order to warp tile by tile
    //current tile size
    int cursizex = 0;
    int cursizey = 0;

    double nbtilex = std::ceil(width/tilesizex);
    double nbtiley = std::ceil(height/tilesizey);

    int starttilex = 0;
    int starttiley = 0;
                
    // Establish reprojection transformer
    psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg =
        GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer(hSrcDS,
                                        GDALGetProjectionRef(hSrcDS),
                                        hDstDS,
                                        GDALGetProjectionRef(hDstDS),
                                        FALSE, 0.0, 1);
    psWarpOptions->pfnTransformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;
    
    // Initialize and execute the warp operation on region
    GDALWarpOperation oOperation;
    oOperation.Initialize(psWarpOptions);
    
    for (int ty = 0; ty < nbtiley; ty++) {
        //handle last tile size
        //if it last tile change size otherwise keep tilesize
        for (int tx = 0; tx < nbtilex; tx++) {
            //if it last tile change size otherwise keep tilesize
            starttiley = ty * tilesizey;
            starttilex = tx * tilesizex;
            
            cursizex = std::min(starttilex + tilesizex, (int)width) - starttilex;
            cursizey = std::min(starttiley + tilesizey, (int)height) - starttiley;

            float * buffer = new float[cursizex*cursizey];
            memset(buffer, 0, cursizex*cursizey);

            //warp source
            CPLErr ret = oOperation.WarpRegionToBuffer(
                starttilex, starttiley, cursizex, cursizey,
                buffer,
                eDT);
            if (ret != 0) {
                CEA_SIMONE_ERROR(CPLGetLastErrorMsg());
                throw std::runtime_error("warp error");
            }
            
            //write the fuzed tile in dest
            ret = GDALRasterIO(GDALGetRasterBand(hDstDS,1),
                GF_Write,
                starttilex, starttiley, cursizex, cursizey,
                buffer, cursizex, cursizey,
                eDT,
                0, 0);
            if (ret != 0) {
                CEA_SIMONE_ERROR("raster io write error");
                throw std::runtime_error("raster io write error");
            }
            delete(buffer);
        }
    }
    
    // Clean memory
    GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer( psWarpOptions->pTransformerArg );
    GDALDestroyWarpOptions( psWarpOptions );
    GDALClose( hDstDS );
    GDALClose( hSrcDS );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The result:
[output image of previous sample of code (as png, as I can't enclose TIF img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttIZV.png)

The GdalWarp command line:

```
gdalwarp -te -1 41 2 45 -tr 0.000833333 0.000833333 in.dt1 out_cmd_line.tif
```

The command line result:
[output image of previous command line (as png, as I can't enclose TIF img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq2d6.png)

Can you please help me find what is wrong with my use of GDAL C/C++ API  in order to have a similar behaviour as gdalwarp command line? There is probably an algorithm in gdalwarp that computes a mask of useful pixels in destination frame before calling WarpRegionToBuffer, but I didn't find it.
I would really appreciate help on this problem!

Best regards